# Is it possible to re-assign a div's childs class in consecutive order with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following situation where my divs childs id's need to be renamed in consecutive order starting from 1.

eg.

```
<div id="parent">  
    <div id="child-108"></div>
    <div id="child-99"></div>
    <div id="child-9"></div>
    <div id="child-18"></div>
    <div id="child-64"></div>
</div>
```

converted via JQuery or regular Javascript into:

```
<div id="parent">  
    <div id="child-1"></div>
    <div id="child-2"></div>
    <div id="child-3"></div>
    <div id="child-4"></div>
    <div id="child-5"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: First of all you are going to need id's that are sortable eg. child-001, child-002 etc. It would be quite difficult to sort the ids as they currently stand.

Comment: @Mark: Not necessarily. My read of the question is that @steve wants to reassign their `id` values based on where they are, not rearrange them according to their `id` values.

Comment: @TJ - Apologies. You're quite right. This makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: @Mark your right on the money!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you can do that with the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
$('#parent > div').each(function(index) {
    this.id = 'child-' + (index + 1);
});
```

The function you pass into `each` is called with `this` pointing at the DOM element and the `index` argument giving the index (starting with `0`) within the selected elements.